# Deque Iterator Error

Tags: c++

I have a `BinNode<Elem>` class for my Binary Search Tree Implementation.

When I initialise the following: `deque< BinNode<Elem>* >::const_iterator iter = n.begin();` I get an error telling me that a colon is expected after deque<>.

Does the deque not support a template argument in a template argument or is this some sort of different error?

Here is a snippet of the function:

```
template <class Key, class Elem, class KEComp, class EEComp>
void BST<Key, Elem, KEComp, EEComp>::
printBranchesHelp(int branchLen, int nodeSpaceLen, int startLen, int nodesInThisLevel, const deque< BinNode<Elem>* >& n, ostream& out)
{
    deque< BinNode<Elem>* >::const_iterator iter = n.begin();
    for (int i = 0; i < nodesInThisLevel / 2; i++) 
    {  
        out << ((i == 0) ? setw(startLen-1) : setw(nodeSpaceLen-2)) << "" << ((*iter++) ? "/" : " ");
        out << setw(2*branchLen+2) << "" << ((*iter++) ? "\\" : " ");
    }
    out << endl;
}
```

Comment: Is `Elem` a template parameter? If so, you might need `typename dequeue< BinNode<Elem>* >::const_iterator`

Comment: Yes TartanLlama, it is.

Comment: BinNode<Elem> is the node of the tree, so I am using a pointer to the node which is of type `BinNode<Elem>`

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us, and also include the actual (complete and unedited) build log as well. Remember to point out the lines with the error(s) in the MCVE.

Comment: How you declared the n?

Comment: Updated OP with more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `deque< BinNode<Elem>* >::const_iterator` is a dependent name, you need to explicitly identify it as a type with the `typename` keyword:

```
typename deque< BinNode<Elem>* >::const_iterator iter = n.begin();
```

You might want to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords) for a better understanding of dependent names and why you need to use `typename`.

If you find yourself needing this type a lot, I'd recommend writing an alias or typedef for it:

```
using deque_iterator = typename deque< BinNode<Elem>* >::const_iterator;
```

Or in C++11 you could just sidestep the issue and use `auto`:

```
auto iter = n.begin();
```

Comment: Looking into it, thank you Tartan. (I think you mean deque and not dequeue)

Comment: Isn't `typename` required just for `Elem` template argument?

Comment: @Zereges the whole name is dependent and could have specializations which expose types or non-types.